# version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongo)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I am installing mongoDb 4.2 on ubuntu-16.04(xenial)

when I am running `sudo service mongod`  status command showing status is active

[image]

But when trying to connect to mongo or mongod I am getting below issue

```
mongo: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
mongo: /usr/lib/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by mongo)
```

[image]

[image]

Hi @D.SM
Here is out put of `ldd $(which mongo)`

```
/usr/local/bin/mongo: /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10: version `libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/mongo)
/usr/local/bin/mongo: /usr/lib/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by /usr/local/bin/mongo)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdc879d000)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007ff22e032000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff22de17000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007ff22d9d2000)
    libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.10 (0x00007ff22d769000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff22d565000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff22d35d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff22d054000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff22ce3e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff22cc21000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff22c857000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff230bf8000)
    libidn.so.11 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11 (0x00007ff22c624000)
    librtmp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 (0x00007ff22c408000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007ff22c1be000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff22bfaf000)
    libldap_r-2.4.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 (0x00007ff22bd5e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff22bb44000)
    libgnutls.so.30 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 (0x00007ff22b814000)
    libhogweed.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4 (0x00007ff22b5e1000)
    libnettle.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6 (0x00007ff22b3ab000)
    libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0x00007ff22b12b000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007ff22ae59000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007ff22ac2a000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007ff22aa26000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007ff22a81b000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 (0x00007ff22a600000)
    libgssapi.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3 (0x00007ff22a3bf000)
    libp11-kit.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 (0x00007ff22a15b000)
    libtasn1.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6 (0x00007ff229f48000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007ff229d44000)
    libheimntlm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0 (0x00007ff229b3b000)
    libkrb5.so.26 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26 (0x00007ff2298b1000)
    libasn1.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8 (0x00007ff22960f000)
    libhcrypto.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4 (0x00007ff2293dc000)
    libroken.so.18 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18 (0x00007ff2291c6000)
    libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007ff228fbe000)
    libwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0 (0x00007ff228d95000)
    libheimbase.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1 (0x00007ff228b86000)
    libhx509.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5 (0x00007ff22893b000)
    libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007ff228666000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff22842e000)
```

Comment: Run `ldd $(which mongo)`, add output to the question. Most likely you either updated the OS without reinstalling MongoDB or you installed MongoDB built for some other OS.

Comment: @D.SMI have added the output in my Question

Comment: MongoDB packages install into /usr, not /usr/local. Remove your existing installation and install following official instructions.